# How to arrange NSString word in this type format without adding space in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to make this type format to word arrange in `NSString` on `UILabel` like

[image]

but I try to make add extra white space according to upper line word length but another way to make this type format suppose using `NSAttributesString`.

Comment: Use Alt+Enter for new line and Alt+Tab for tab in UILabel Text property in xib/storyboard. And change Line property to 0.

Comment: @Shreyank i want to make its in programmatically to arrange this format

Comment: `lblName.text = @"FirstLine\n\tSecondLine\n\t\tThirdLine";` Just Do like this.

Comment: Don't forget to set the number of lines = 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `NSMutableAttributedString` without adding extra white space.

First, create a method that returns `NSMutableAttributedString` like this-

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)setIndent:(NSString*) title value:(CGFloat) value {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style =  [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    style.firstLineHeadIndent = value;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style}];
    return attrText;
}
```

and use this method by the following way -

```
    NSString *title = @"Charlie Chapline Cartoon";

    NSArray* foo = [title componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrText5 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    CGFloat value = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i< foo.count; i++){
        //change this value according to your need.
        value = value + 20.0f;
        [attrText5 appendAttributedString:[self setIndent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", foo[i]] value:value]];
    }

    _myLab.numberOfLines = 5;
    _myLab.attributedText = attrText5;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer, i try to make dynamic space add before word Thanks